# Are the tenses "preterito perfecto" and "perfecto compuesto" the same tense?

Tags: gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales

I wanted to ask you guys if they are the same?
Because I didn't find any exercises on line for "perfecto compuesto".

Answer (score 1):

It seems the name of the tenses you mention are somewhat incomplete. Taking the verb "cantar" as example, you have two differentes tenses in the indicative mood:

- Pretérito perfecto simple: yo canté, tú cantaste...
- Pretérito perfecto compuesto: yo he cantado, tú has cantado...

The main difference is that the simple tense emphasises the fact that the action is in the past, and the compound tense takes the present as the consequence of the past action.

Comment: Part of the confusion may come from the fact that, at least in the English-speaking world, when teaching Spanish we tend to shorten the names of conjugations — *canté, cantaste…* is just "preterite" and books will call it simple "el pretérito".  *he cantado…* is called "pretérito perfecto" (or sometimes even "presente perfecto", since that we call it "present perfect" in English).  It's until students get to more advanced levels that they tend to start calling things by the names used in Spanish

Comment: A mí me enseñaron el tiempo simple como "préterito indefinido" y el compuesto como "pretérito perfecto".

Comment: @pablodf76 es probable, a mí también me suena que me lo enseñaran así (en los albores de los tiempos), en la respuesta he reflejado lo que pone en la RAE cuando le das a conjugar un verbo desde el diccionario.

Comment: @pablodf76 (y Carlos) hay unos sistemas que se ha empleado a lo largo del tiempo para denominar los tiempos. *Canté...* se ha llamado, entre quizás otros, *pretérito indefinido*, *pretérito (perfecto)*, *pretérito perfecto simple*, y las formas *he cantado* han llevado nombres tan diversos como *pretérito perfecto*, *pretérito perfecto compuesto*, *presente perfecto* y *antepresente*.

Comment: @guifa pues que sepas que eso da para una pregunta tela de chula.